# Select columns by regex matching

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I know there a lot of posts on this, but I couldn't find any that helped. What I'm trying to do is simple.

I want to select (or drop) columns based on whether a letter is present in a column name.

```
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

xy <- tibble("x" = 1:5, "123" = 6:10, "x123" = 11:15)

#does not have expected output
> xy %>% select(-matches("[:alpha:]"))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      x `123`  x123
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    11
2     2     7    12
3     3     8    13
4     4     9    14
5     5    10    15
```

But if I use `str_view_all` all the results are as expected, but doesn't work with the `dplyr` helper function `matches` for selecting columns.

```
str_view_all(x, "[:alpha:]")
```

[image]

I'm looking for a solution using `stringr` and `dplyr` if possible. It seems like this should be very straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[:alpha:]` is a POSIX character class that is only valid inside a bracketed expression. So you need an extra pair of brackets:

```
xy <- tibble("x" = 1:5, "123" = 6:10, "x123" = 11:15)

xy %>% select(-matches("[[:alpha:]]"))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  `123`
  <int>
1     6
2     7
3     8
4     9
5    10
```

Comment: *facepalm.* okay that works brilliantly. Just curious why you don't need the extra bracket when using `str_view_all` for example.

Comment: @LloydChristmas Good question that I do not have an answer to. `[:alpha:]` is what is called a POSIX character class and will only be evaluated as such **inside** a bracketed expression `[...]`. `[:alpha:]` by itself would just mean that you're matching the characters `:`, `a`, `l`, `p`, `h` literally. This is why it puzzles me why your `str_view_all` example works in the first place.